# Select * from View takes 4 minutes

Tags: sql-server

I am running in to an issue where when I run a query against a view it takes 4+ minutes.  However, when I run the guts of the query it finishes in like 1 second.

The only thing I am not sure about is the tables being joined are both temporal tables.

Ad hoc query plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BykohB2p4

View query plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkIfTHh6E

Any suggestions on where to try and figure this out?

View code:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwDealHistoryPITA]
AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cm.CodeMasterID ORDER BY cm.CodeMasterID, cm.LastUpdateDate) AS Deal_HistoryID,
       cm.CodeMasterID,
       cm.ProjectName,
       cm.[Status],
       d.CompanyID,
       d.DealTypeMasterID,
       cm.[Description],
       d.PassiveInd,
       d.ApproxTPGOwnership,
       d.NumberBoardSeats,
       d.FollowonInvestmentInd,
       d.SocialImpactInd,
       d.EquityInd,
       d.DebtInd,
       d.RealEstateInd,
       d.TargetPctgReturn,
       d.ApproxTotalDealSize,
       cm.CurrencyCode,
       d.ConflictCheck,
       cm.CreatedDate,
       cm.CreatedBy,
       cm.LastUpdateDate,
       cm.LastUpdateBy,
       d.ExpensesExceedThresholdDate,
       d.CurrentTPGCheckSize,
       d.PreferredEquityInd,
       d.ConvertibleDebtInd,
       d.OtherRealAssetsInd,
       d.InitialTPGCheckSize,
       d.DirectLendingInd,
       cm.NameApproved,
       cm.FolderID,
       cm.CodaProcessedDateTime,
       cm.DeadDate,
       d.SectorMasterID,
       d.DTODataCompleteDate,
       cm.ValidFrom AS CodeMasterValidFrom,
       cm.ValidTo   AS CodeMasterValidTo,
       d.validFrom  AS DealValidFrom,
       d.validTo    AS DealValidTo
FROM dbo.CodeMaster FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL cm 
INNER JOIN dbo.Deal FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL d ON cm.CodeMasterID = d.CodeMasterID;
GO
```

Added the Partition by and get similar results to the ad hoc query.

Answer (score 19):

### The main performance differences

The main differences here are that the better performing query is pushing down the seek predicate on `CodeMasterID` on all 4 tables (2 temporal tables (actual & history)) where the select on the view appears to not do that until the end *(filter operator)*.

**TL DR;**

The issue is due to to parameters not pushing down to window functions in certain cases such as views. The easiest solution is adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the view call as to make the optimizer 'see' the params at runtime if that is a possibility. If it is too expensive to recompile the execution plan for each query call, using an inline table valued function that expects a parameter could be a solution.

See [The Problem with Window Functions and Views](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/t-sql-queries/the-problem-with-window-functions-and-views) by [Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white).

*For a more detailed way on finding and resolving your particular issue, keep on reading.*

---

**The better performing query**

*Codemaster table*

[image]

[image]

*Deal table*

[image]

[image]

*I love the smell of seek predicates in the morning*

---

**The big bad query**

**Codemaster table**

[image]

[image]

*This is a predicate only zone*

**The Deal table**

[image]

*But the optimizer did not read 'The art of the deal™"*

[image]

*...and does not learn from the past*

**Until all that data reaches the filter operator**

[image]

---

### So, what gives?

The main problem here is the optimizer not 'seeing' the parameters at runtime due to the window functions in the view and not being able to use the `SelOnSeqPrj` *(select on sequence project, further down in this post for reference)*.

I was able to replicate the same results with a test sample and using `SP_EXECUTESQL` to parameterize the call to the view. *See addendum for the DDL / DML*

**executing a query against a test view with a window function and an `INNER JOIN`**

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
N'SELECT * FROM  dbo.Bad
Where CodeMasterID = @P1',N'@P1 INT',@P1 = 37155;
```

*Resulting in about 4.5s of cpu time and 3.2s elapsed time*

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 4595 ms,  elapsed time = 3209 ms.
```

**When we add the sweet embrace of `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`**

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
N'SELECT * FROM  dbo.Bad
Where CodeMasterID = @P1 OPTION(RECOMPILE)',N'@P1 INT',@P1 = 37155;
```

*It is all good.*

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 98 ms.
```

**Why**

This all again supports the point of not being able to apply the `@P1` predicate to the tables because of the window function & parameterization resulting in the filter operator

[image]
[image]

**Not only an issue for temporal tables**

*See addendum 2*

Even when not using temporal tables, this happens:
[image]

**The same result is seen when writing the query like this:**

```
DECLARE @P1 int = 37155
SELECT * FROM  dbo.Bad2
Where CodeMasterID = @P1;
```

*Again, the optimizer is not pushing down the predicate before applying the window function.*

**When omitting the ROW_NUMBER()**

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Bad3
as
SELECT
cm.CodeMasterID,CM.ManagerID,cm.ParentDeptID,d.DealID, d.CodeMasterID as dealcodemaster,d.EvenMoreBlaID
FROM dbo.CodeMaster2  cm 
INNER JOIN dbo.Deal2  d ON cm.CodeMasterID = d.CodeMasterID;
```

**All is well**

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
N'SELECT * FROM  dbo.Bad3
Where CodeMasterID = @P1',N'@P1 INT',@P1 = 37155


 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 33 ms.
```

**so where does all that leave us?**

The `ROW_NUMBER()` is calculated before the filter is applied on the bad queries.

And all this leads us to [this blogpost](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/t-sql-queries/the-problem-with-window-functions-and-views) from 2013 by [Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white)
on window functions and views.

One of the important parts for our example is this statement:

> Unfortunately, the SelOnSeqPrj simplification rule only works when the
> predicate performs a comparison with a constant. For that reason, the
> following query produces the sub-optimal plan on SQL Server 2008 and
> later:

```
DECLARE @ProductID INT = 878;
 
SELECT
    mrt.ProductID,
    mrt.TransactionID,
    mrt.ReferenceOrderID,
    mrt.TransactionDate,
    mrt.Quantity
FROM dbo.MostRecentTransactionsPerProduct AS mrt 
WHERE
    mrt.ProductID = @ProductID;
```

[image]

This part corresponds to what we have seen when declaring the parameter ourselves / using `SP_EXECUTESQL` on the view.

---

### The actual solutions

**1: OPTION(RECOMPILE)**

We know that `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to 'see' the value at runtime is a possibility. When recompiling the execution plan for each query call is too expensive, there are other solutions.

**2: Inline table valued function with a parameter**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.BlaBla
(
    @P1 INT
)  
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
    (
     SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cm.CodeMasterID ORDER BY cm.CodeMasterID) AS Deal_HistoryID,
     cm.CodeMasterID,CM.ManagerID,
     cm.ParentDeptID,d.DealID,
     d.CodeMasterID as dealcodemaster,
     d.EvenMoreBlaID
    FROM dbo.CodeMaster2  cm 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Deal2  d ON cm.CodeMasterID = d.CodeMasterID
    Where cm.CodeMasterID = @P1
    ) 
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
N'SELECT * FROM  dbo.BlaBLa(@P1)',N'@P1 INT',@P1 = 37155
```

*Resulting in the expected seek predicates*

```
     SQL Server Execution Times:
       CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

*With about 9 logical reads on my test*

**3: Writing the query without the use of a view.**

The other 'solution' could be writing the query entirely without the use of a view.

**4: Not keeping the `ROW_NUMBER()` function in the view, instead specifying it in the call to the view.**

An example of this would be:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Bad2
as
SELECT 
cm.CodeMasterID,CM.ManagerID,cm.ParentDeptID,d.DealID, d.CodeMasterID as dealcodemaster,d.EvenMoreBlaID
FROM dbo.CodeMaster2  cm 
INNER JOIN dbo.Deal2  d ON cm.CodeMasterID = d.CodeMasterID;

GO
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
N'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CodeMasterID ORDER BY CodeMasterID) AS Deal_HistoryID,* FROM  dbo.Bad2
Where CodeMasterID = @P1',N'@P1 INT',@P1 = 37155;
```

*There should be other creative ways around this issue, the important part is knowing what causes it.*

---

**Addendum #1**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Codemaster   
(    
     CodeMasterID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
   , ManagerID INT  NULL  
   , ParentDeptID int NULL  
   , SysStartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL  
   , SysEndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL  
   , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime,SysEndTime)     
)    
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.Codemaster_History))   
;  

CREATE TABLE dbo.Deal   
(    
     DealID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
   , CodeMasterID INT  NULL  
   , EvenMoreBlaID int NULL  
   , SysStartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL  
   , SysEndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL  
   , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime,SysEndTime)     
)    
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.Deal_History))   
;  

INSERT INTO dbo.Codemaster(CodeMasterID,ManagerID,ParentDeptID)
SELECT TOP(1000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) as rownum1,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) as rownum2,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) as rownum3
FROM MASTER..spt_values as spt1
CROSS JOIN MASTER..spt_values as spt2;


INSERT INTO dbo.Deal(DealID,CodeMasterID,EvenMoreBlaID)
SELECT TOP(1000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) as rownum1,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) as rownum2,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) as rownum3
FROM MASTER..spt_values as spt1
CROSS JOIN MASTER..spt_values as spt2;

CREATE INDEX IX_CodeMasterID
ON dbo.Deal(CodeMasterId);
CREATE INDEX IX_CodeMasterID
ON dbo.Deal_History(CodeMasterId);

CREATE INDEX IX_CodeMasterID
ON dbo.Codemaster(CodeMasterId);
CREATE INDEX IX_CodeMasterID
ON dbo.Codemaster_History(CodeMasterId);


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cm.CodeMasterID ORDER BY cm.CodeMasterID, cm.SysStartTime) AS Deal_HistoryID,
cm.*, d.* 
FROM dbo.CodeMaster FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL cm 
INNER JOIN dbo.Deal FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL d ON cm.CodeMasterID = d.CodeMasterID
Where cm.CodeMasterID = 37155;

-- Guud
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.Bad
as
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cm.CodeMasterID ORDER BY cm.CodeMasterID, cm.SysStartTime) AS Deal_HistoryID,
cm.CodeMasterID,CM.ManagerID,cm.ParentDeptID,d.DealID, d.CodeMasterID as dealcodemaster,d.EvenMoreBlaID
FROM dbo.CodeMaster FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL cm 
INNER JOIN dbo.Deal FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL d ON cm.CodeMasterID = d.CodeMasterID

GO
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
N'SELECT * FROM  dbo.Bad
Where CodeMasterID = @P1',N'@P1 INT',@P1 = 37155

-- Very bad shame on you
```

---

**Addendum #2**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Codemaster2
(    
     CodeMasterID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
   , ManagerID INT  NULL  
   , ParentDeptID int NULL  
 
);  

CREATE TABLE dbo.Deal2
(    
     DealID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
   , CodeMasterID INT  NULL  
   , EvenMoreBlaID int NULL    
);  

INSERT INTO dbo.Codemaster2(CodeMasterID,ManagerID,ParentDeptID)
SELECT TOP(1000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) as rownum1,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) as rownum2,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) as rownum3
FROM MASTER..spt_values as spt1
CROSS JOIN MASTER..spt_values as spt2;


INSERT INTO dbo.Deal2(DealID,CodeMasterID,EvenMoreBlaID)
SELECT TOP(1000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) as rownum1,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) as rownum2,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) as rownum3
FROM MASTER..spt_values as spt1
CROSS JOIN MASTER..spt_values as spt2;

CREATE INDEX IX_CodeMasterID
ON dbo.Deal2(CodeMasterId);
CREATE INDEX IX_CodeMasterID
ON dbo.Codemaster2(CodeMasterId);


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cm.CodeMasterID ORDER BY cm.CodeMasterId) AS Deal_HistoryID,
cm.*, d.* 
FROM dbo.CodeMaster2 cm 
INNER JOIN dbo.Deal2 d ON cm.CodeMasterID = d.CodeMasterID
Where cm.CodeMasterID = 37155;

-- Guud
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.Bad2
as
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cm.CodeMasterID ORDER BY cm.CodeMasterID) AS Deal_HistoryID,
cm.CodeMasterID,CM.ManagerID,cm.ParentDeptID,d.DealID, d.CodeMasterID as dealcodemaster,d.EvenMoreBlaID
FROM dbo.CodeMaster2  cm 
INNER JOIN dbo.Deal2  d ON cm.CodeMasterID = d.CodeMasterID

GO
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
N'SELECT * FROM  dbo.Bad2
Where CodeMasterID = @P1',N'@P1 INT',@P1 = 37155
```

Answer (score -3):

I think, the problem was fixed these days with SQL Server 2017 CU 30:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb5013756-cumulative-update-30-for-sql-server-2017-274943fa-8dde-4844-90ed-d3b587fa0c7c#bkmk_14783868