# How do I force SQL Server to use my spatial index through a view?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, spatial

I have tables which holds transactions for properties that are stored as lat long pairs. (There are more columns and datapoints then in my example schema).

A common request is to find the transactions that happened within X miles of a particular point, and only retrieve the 5 most recent transactions that happened for each nearby property.

To make this work, I decided to add a view that encapsulates this logic of most recent:

```
create or alter view dbo.v_example
with schemabinding as
select example_id
      ,transaction_dt
      ,latitude
      ,longitude
      ,latlong
      ,most_recent= iif(row_number() over (partition by latitude,longitude order by transaction_dt desc) < 5,1,null)
from dbo.example;
```

So a query might look like this::

```sql
select *
from dbo.v_example
where latlong.STDistance(geography::Point(40,-74,4326)) <=1609.344e1
and most_recent = 1
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server  does not want to use the spatial index when I query through the view. If I remove `schemabinding` and try to add a hint on the view, I get that the query processor cannot create a plan.

How can I encapsulate the logic and still get it to use my spatial index?

[Here's a db<>fiddle with example data and plan shapes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=17b7a0037882e8ce0129fa42fade4764).

The table is much larger, and it is much slower to scan it then to do a clustered index seek and then find the near by point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Window functions & Views**

Recently I answered a different question regarding views & window functions but not all answers given there apply here.

Two differences are that this example uses `geography` datatypes and filters on the window function. The positive part here is that you are not bound to the window function and could use something like `CROSS APPLY` to get the closest results for one `latitude` & `longitude` combination.

[The previous question + Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239370/select-from-view-takes-4-minutes/239396#239396)

**In short**, the window function is calculated before the filtering is applied.

E.G.

```
where latlong.STDistance(geography::Point(40,-74,4326)) <=1609.344e1
and most_recent = 1
```

Extra information can be found in [this blogpost](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/t-sql-queries/the-problem-with-window-functions-and-views)  from 2013 by [Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white) on window functions and views.

**Testing**

As a first test, the result is clear when omitting the `ROW_NUMBER()` from the view

```
create or alter view dbo.v_example2
with schemabinding as
select example_id
      ,transaction_dt
      ,latitude
      ,longitude
      ,latlong
from dbo.example;

set statistics xml on;
select *
from dbo.v_example2
where latlong.STDistance(geography::Point(40,-74,4326)) <=1609.344e1
```

Resulting in the expected performant query plan.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cebca27b4970a1ce1b774d41884674b7)

---

### But you obviously still want the additional filtering

**Keeping the view + window function**

You could choose to add the window function afterwards like so:

```
create or alter view dbo.v_example2
with schemabinding as
select example_id
      ,transaction_dt
      ,latitude
      ,longitude
      ,latlong
from dbo.example;
```

&

```
set statistics xml on;
;WITH CTE AS
(
select most_recent= iif(row_number() over (partition by latitude,longitude order by transaction_dt desc) < 5,1,null)
,*
from dbo.v_example2
where latlong.STDistance(geography::Point(40,-74,4326)) <=1609.344e1
)
SELECT
* 
FROM CTE
WHERE most_recent is not null;
```

Again resulting in the expected execution plan.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0e2beee6e8228ad6ce743faef4e5daf9)

---

**Using an inline table valued function  + window function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F_Example
(
    @P1 INT

)  
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
    (
SELECT example_id
      ,transaction_dt
      ,latitude
      ,longitude
      ,latlong
      ,most_recent FROM
(
select example_id
      ,transaction_dt
      ,latitude
      ,longitude
      ,latlong
      ,most_recent= iif(row_number() over (partition by latitude,longitude order by transaction_dt desc) < 5,1,null)
from dbo.example
WHERE latlong.STDistance(geography::Point(40,-74,4326)) <= 1609.344e1
) AS A
WHERE most_recent= @P1
);

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
N'SELECT * FROM  dbo.F_Example(@P1)',N'@P1 INT',@P1 = 1
```

**Resulting in the query plan you expected.**

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0d253d4259a81433db008a144a819e80)

**Using a CTE + window function**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
select example_id
      ,transaction_dt
      ,latitude
      ,longitude
      ,latlong
      ,most_recent= row_number() over (partition by latitude,longitude order by transaction_dt desc)
FROM dbo.example
WHERE latlong.STDistance(geography::Point(40,-74,4326)) <=1609.344e1
)

SELECT example_id
      ,transaction_dt
      ,latitude
      ,longitude
      ,latlong
      ,most_recent
FROM CTE2
WHERE most_recent < 5;
```

**Using `CROSS APPLY` and `TOP(4)` *without the window function***

```
SELECT example_id
      ,a.transaction_dt
      ,latitude
      ,longitude
      ,latlong
from dbo.example e1
CROSS APPLY(
SELECT TOP(4) transaction_dt
FROM dbo.example e2
WHERE e1.latitude = e2.latitude  and e1.longitude = e2.longitude
GROUP BY latitude,longitude,transaction_dt
ORDER BY transaction_dt desc
) as a
WHERE latlong.STDistance(geography::Point(40,-74,4326)) <=1609.344e1
AND e1.transaction_dt = a.transaction_dt
ORDER BY transaction_dt desc;
```

I used `top(4)` since the resultset was based on `< 5` not `<= 5`

When using the `CROSS APPLY` method there is one more index to be added, to remove the index spool & sort:

[image]

```
CREATE INDEX IX_latitude_longitude_transaction_dt
ON dbo.example(latitude,longitude,transaction_dt);
```

[image]

It goes without saying that you could add the `CROSS APPLY` solution to a view and query it the same way as you used to, an example of this [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1fd01fb011a3cb5c6f44d45ea1a7b4c3).
All above examples in [one DB<>Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0ee10a63a1551a08acbbfc448e2c11e2).

---

**End solution comment by [MichaelB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/47354/michael-b)**

> Thanks Randi, I was able to rewrite my logic into a select subquery
>   using the idea of your cross apply. As an added bonus, if I don't
>   mention the field in the columns I select, I do not get a performance
>   hit.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9cc843e8b8cc9ba3fd56650b522a450e)

```
create or alter view dbo.v_example2
with schemabinding as
select example_id
      ,transaction_dt
      ,latitude
      ,longitude
      ,latlong
      ,most_recent= (
          select a.transaction_dt
          intersect
          select top 5 b.transaction_dt
          from dbo.example b
          where a.latitude=b.latitude
                and a.longitude=b.longitude
          order by transaction_dt desc
      )
from dbo.example a;
```

&

```
select example_id
      ,transaction_dt
      ,latitude
      ,longitude
      ,latlong
from dbo.v_example2
where latlong.STDistance(geography::Point(40,-74,4326)) <=1609.344e1
      and most_recent is not null
```

Comment: Is there some way to tell it that the geography with the same lat long are identical? I guess that's the issue. Normally, if this was like `property_id` and I did a query like `where property_id=1 and most_recent is not null`. It will play ball.

Comment: @MichaelB I added one method with `CROSS APPLY ` instead of the window function, returning the  `TOP(4) ` and basing the filters on  `LAT ` &  `LONG `. Would that be something that would help with the identical results ( `Top(4) ` per identical  `lat & long `).

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake when I created the example view. My issue is that my app is querying this data via EF Core. EF Core does not support ranking functions as far as I can tell, so I was trying to work around it by using a view to do it.

Comment: @MichaelB you could encapsulate the `CROSS APPLY ` alternative in a view? [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1fd01fb011a3cb5c6f44d45ea1a7b4c3)

Comment: Thanks Randi, I was able to rewrite my logic into a select subquery using the idea of your cross apply. As an added bonus, if I don't mention the field in the columns I select, I do not get a performance hit. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9cc843e8b8cc9ba3fd56650b522a450e

Comment: @MichaelB Great to hear! Thank you for taking the time to give an update and the end solution you used :)

Comment: No problem. Honestly, my first approach to this type of thing has always been to use ranking functions ever since I used Sql 2008. While putting my logic in a cross apply worked, I was disappointed that the most recent predicate was always being applied. Even with an index, there was a slow down in the common case. Using the subquery in the select is usually a big no-no for me due to poor readability of it, and is semantically equivalent to a cross apply. I think this is related to Paul's article that because it's in the view it must be executed.